# How do I change my $JAVA_HOME variable to match the location of my Java installation?

Tags: java

I am trying to build my Ionic app and run it in an android emulator. However, I  continue to get this error:

[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJXax.png)

My Java installation *seems* to be in the same place as my $JAVA_HOME variable. How can I ensure they are in the same location? If I have to uninstall and reinstall software too, that's fine.

Comment: $JAVA_HOME should be a folder, not a file. In your case probably /usr/bin. /usr/bin/java is a binary file.

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.